# How to Subtract Values Within Two Lists

Tags: r

I have two lists of animal tracking data. Each list contains the animal ID and a list of utm coordinates. My lists look something like this:

list1

| list1 | List[2] | List of length 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TM1 | integer[3] | 300,350,200 |
| TM2 | integer[2] | 175,150 |

list2

| list2 | List[2] | List of length 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TM1 | double[3] | 315,345,205 |
| TM2 | double[2] | 170,165 |

What I would like to do is subtract the coordinates for each individual to get a final list that looks something like this:

| X | List[2] | List of length 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TM1 | integer[3] | 15,-5,5 |
| TM2 | integer[2] | -5,15 |

I tried setting up a for loop to subtract the values (just a note, df here is a placeholder for the original dataframe of length 2):

```
'''r
coord.diff<-list()
for(i in 1:length(df)){
coord.diff[i]<-(list2[[i]]-list1[[i]])
}
'''r
```

which returns the following errors:

```
'''r
1: In coord.diff[i] <- (list2[[i]] - list1[[i]]) :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In coord.diff[i] <- (list2[[i]] - list1[[i]]) :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
'''r
```

Oddly enough however, when I do the following I actually get the list of differences that I want:

```
'''r
list2[[1]]-list1[[1]]
'''r
```

but I would like to be able to automate the process through a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One fast solution within the `tidyverse` is to use the `purrr` package, more specifically the `purrr::map2` function, which works on two inputs:

```
# set up dummy data
list1 <- list(TM1 = c(300, 350, 200),
              TM2 = c(175,150))

list2 <- list(TM1 = c(315, 345, 205),
              TM2 = c(170,165))

# apply map2 function defining list inputs and performin the operation 
# (y = list2, x = list1)
purrr::map2(list1, list2, ~.y - .x)

$TM1
[1] 15 -5  5

$TM2
[1] -5 15
```

For better comprehention, if the mathematical operation to apply has more complexity i.e., you can define the function to apply seperately and apply it via the `purrr::map2` call:

```
myfun <- function(x, y){
    ret <- y - x
    return(ret)
}

purrr::map2(list1, list2, ~ myfun(.x, .y))

$TM1
[1] 15 -5  5

$TM2
[1] -5 15
```

The base R option would look something like this, using `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(x ,y) {
    ret <- y - x
    return(ret)
}, 
x = list1, y = list2)

$TM1
[1] 15 -5  5

$TM2
[1] -5 15
```

as @onyambu pointed out in the comment this is consice base are approach:

```
Map(`-`, list1, list2)

$TM1
[1] -15   5  -5

$TM2
[1]   5 -15
```

This simplification can also be used with the `purrr::map2()` call as @onyambu pointed out also in the comments:

```
purrr::map2(list2, list1, `-`)

$TM1
[1] 15 -5  5

$TM2
[1] -5 15
```

Comment: base R: `Map(\`-\`, list1, list2)`

Comment: if you need the negation `Map("-", list2, list1)`

Comment: `purrr::map2(list2, list1, \`-\`)`